# Filtering groups in targeted query with Apps Script returns "forbidden"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

When trying to run this reports query, Apps Script returns a "Forbidden" error.

```
var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(
  'channel==' + channel,
  startDate,
  yesterdayFormatted,
  'views',
  {
    filters: 'group==' + groupID
  });
```

The same query works just fine through the query explorer web UI.

I tried groups created through the API as well as through the Youtube Analytics web UI.

The groups are all older than 48 hours.

The query runs fine with any other filter in multiple scripts with different metrics, sorts, etc.

Youtube Data and Reporting API permissions are set for the script and for the project.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: have the same issue, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: still hoping for an answer. didn't find any thing.